# Android Google Map v2 Marker Not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to plot a marker with specific co-ordinates in Google map v2 but it doesnt show the marker on the given Position.

I did go to google but didn't find anything helpful any help please...

```
    if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
     double latitude = 13.094192 ;
     double longitude = 80.121689;
     MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

// adding marker

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: post your code what you tried..

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: the above link i followed

Comment: Could please post your actual code? Thanks.

Comment: fasteque please chck the code i posted Thanks

Comment: where do you add the marker? You posted the line but we don't know where you call it. Just after the marker creation? Please copy the full code.

Comment: Finally got it, its problem with braces while checking for googlemap ==null

Comment: Good, that's why I asked you to post the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change with this:

```
if (googleMap !=null){
  Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
      .title("Hello Maps"));

}
```